# extract words from string including parentheses

Tags: regex, scala

I am novice to Scala.

`val str = "Hi My name (is XXX)"`
I tried splitting by using `str.split("\\s")` and creates string Array like this:
0: Hi 
1: My
2: name
3: (is
4: XXX)

I would like to get
0: Hi
1: My
2: name 
3: (is XXX)
Is there any quick way to do that in Scala

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex as well, although it won't work for nested parens.

```
(\([^)]+\)|\S+)
```

Test in console:

```
@ """(\([^)]+\)|\S+)""".r.findAllIn("Hi My name (is XXX)").toList
res8: List[String] = List("Hi", "My", "name", "(is XXX)")
@ """(\([^)]+\)|\S+)""".r.findAllIn("(A B) C D (E F G) H").toList
res9: List[String] = List("(A B)", "C", "D", "(E F G)", "H")
@ """(\([^)]+\)|\S+)""".r.findAllIn("Z (A B) C D (E F G) H").toList
res10: List[String] = List("Z", "(A B)", "C", "D", "(E F G)", "H")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will split on whitespace, but always keep things between parentheses intact.

```
def splitWithParens(s: String) = 
  s.split("[()]").grouped(2).flatMap {
    case Array(a,b) => a.split("\\s+").filter(_.nonEmpty) :+ s"($b)"
    case Array(a) => a.split("\\s+").filter(_.nonEmpty)
  }.toVector

splitWithParens("Hi My name (is XXX)")    // Vector(Hi, My, name, (is XXX))
splitWithParens("(A B) C D (E F G) H")    // Vector((A B), C, D, (E F G), H)
splitWithParens("Z (A B) C D (E F G) H")  // Vector(Z, (A B), C, D, (E F G), H)
```